# Fill a defined 2D Array with random numbers in C / Average / Max Value

Tags: c, arrays, random

I've created this 2D 21x21 array that has all it's values set to -1. I wrote it to print the address and value and somehow it only starts at [6][19] why?

What i want to do is to replace some of the -1 values with random numbers from 0 to 100 in the same array. I know i need to seed it with srand but i'm having problems connecting the functions since i'm a total beginner in C.

EDIT 1:

Now i can print the whole array and fill it with random numbers. For the -1 values i just assigned directly which for this case its fine.

What i'm trying now is finding the average of all the values and the maximum number, so what i have is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 


int main()
{

int a[21][21], i , j;

for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < 21; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = GetRand(0, 100);
        a[7][15] = -1;
        a[10][6] = -1;
        a[13][5] = -1;
        a[15][17] = -1;
        a[17][17] = -1;
        a[19][6] = -1;
        printf("%3d" , a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}



// random seed
int GetRand(int min, int max);
int get() {
 int i, r;
for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)
 {
r = GetRand(0, 100);
printf("Your number is %d \n", r);
 }
 return(0);
 }

int GetRand(int min, int max)
{
static int Init = 0;
int rc;

if (Init == 0)
{
srand(time(NULL));
Init = 1;
}

rc = (rand() % (max - min +1) +min);

return (rc);
}



// average

int avg()

float sum=0.0;

for(i = 0; i <= 21; i = i + 1) {


    for(j = 0; j <= 21; j = j + 1){


         sum = sum + a[21][21];
     }

printf("The the average number is %.2f\n", sum/21);
}




 //find maximum of all values    

 int *pv = &a[0][0];
 max = min = 0;
 for (i = 1; i < i*j; ++i){
    if (pv[i] > pv[max])
        max =i;
    if (pv[i] < pv[min])
        min = i;
}
printf("The max value is %d in row %d, col %d\n", pv[max], max/j, max%j);


return 0;
}
```

For the average function the compiler tells me that expected a declaration before i, which is "float sum=0.0;" but i haven't been able to fix that yet.

For the finding the max function i'm not sure yet what i'm doing there, i just have a vague idea of how it's done...am i going in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: `a[i][j] = GetRand(0, 100);` instead of `a[i][j] = -1;`

Comment: I'm not convinced the actual problem and your description of the problem match up here.  You say it "starts at [6][19]".  I bet that has more to do with the scrollback buffer in your terminal.  Try piping the output through `more` or `less`.  The other part appears to be confusion about how to compile and link multiple source files.  Of course, you could just include the code for `GetRand` in your other source file.  You won't be able to link these two source files unless `main` only appears in one of them.

Comment: My bad about the output. So i wrote a[i][j] = GetRand(0, 100); instead of a[i][j] = -1; And now my array has random numbers from 0 to 100, my problem is i need it to have some -1 values.

For example:
[2][3]=9
[2][4]=-1
[2][5]=23
[2][6]=-1

and i have no idea how i can achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple: Just assign the result of your `GetRand` function to the matrix entry.